# CUDA Performance comparison for Computer Vision applications

Tags: opencv, cuda, computer-vision, gpu

I am currently working on performance comparison of various computer vision applications. The research is based on evaluating how these different algorithms perform on CUDA and OpenMP.

Do you have any source codes in CUDA as well as the serial implementation in C for these kind of applications?
Where can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

[The CUDA SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) is full of examples, compiled both on GPU and CPU.

sources are included.

[Here is a list of the samples you get by installing it.](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html)

You could start from here :)